# Testing the Standard Model Lagrangian

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, experimental-physics, standard-model, scattering-cross-section

When we measure cross-sections of Standard Model predicted processes, are we actually only testing the interaction terms of the corresponding Lagrangian?

Comment: What do you mean by "only"? Based on how the question is worded, it seems like you are expecting to be able to test additional things, can you elaborate on what these are? I think it would help frame an answer. In case this is what you are asking, the non-interaction (quadratic) terms in the Lagrangian are also tested/measured, and experiments also constrain interaction terms that are not in the Standard Model Lagrangian but could have been there.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks a lot for your comment, my apologies for the unclear question, but I was actually wondering what parts of the Lagrangian are we testing when we measure cross sections, i.e. can we say that the full Lagrangian is being validated when we find an agreement between SM and data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just think about a simple $\phi^4$ theory
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 - \frac{1}{4!} \lambda \phi^4
\end{equation}

At tree level, the Feynman diagram for a four-point interaction is just the coupling constant, $\lambda$. (up to a factor of $-i$ or so).

The *cross section* depends on additional parameters beyond $\lambda$.

First, the cross section involves an *integral over available phase space*. This leads to cross sections depending on the energy and masses of the particles involved, which you can think of as coming from the quadratic terms.

Second, *loop corrections* will correct the tree-level vertex, and typically will introduce dependence on the energy and mass.

If we had additional fields in our Lagrangian, the masses, energies, and couplings of those fields will also enter into the cross section.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew, that makes more sense to me!

Comment: One might add that a possible coefficient in front of the kinetic term can be absorbed in a field redefinition, so it is not actually an additiona parameter to be tested.

Comment: @Toffomat Thanks for the comment. I'll think about how to phrase it, but you can't do this rescaling if the coefficient of the kinetic term is zero, and if the coefficient is the wrong sign you have a ghost instability that you can't remove with a rescaling. I'm not saying the resulting theory won't make a lot of sense, but just as a point of principle I think it's fair that the cross section is sensitive to the kinetic term.

Comment: But if @Toffomat means that the Lagrangian itself is multiplied by some factor, the physics do not change when deriving the e.o.m., that holds right?

Comment: @StackExchanger You have to be careful with that. Classically, if you multiply the *whole* action by a constant, it doesn't matter. Quantum mechanically, since the path integral is $\int D\Phi e^{i S/\hbar}$, the overall scaling of the action *does* matter. But anyway, the sign of the kinetic term (positive, negative, or zero) is not something you can change with a rescaling, and the physics does depend on the sign.